# Unable to add new key value into an existing JSON Array with JSON objects

Tags: json, node.js

Here is what I have tried.
I have tried dot notation and quotes. None of them seem to work. What exactly could be the problem?

```
var clientsList;

Client.find({}, function(err, clients) {
    clientsList = clients; 
   // I have 10 clients in the loop 
   for (var j = 0; j < clientsList.length; j++) {
            var x =  clientsList[j];
            x.count = "20";
            //x["count"] = "20";
            console.log(x);
        }

});
```

Existing Client object

```
{"name":"abcd", "email":"abc@gmail.com"}
```

I'm unable to add the **count** key value pair into the client object. What could be the problem?

Comment: Are the objects non-extensible or something? Not enough in the existing code to tell

Comment: There's no JSON in your question at all. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: @CertainPerformance sorry, updated query.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the object you're being given by `Client.find` has extensions prevented (it's [sealed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal) or [frozen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)).

You can create a *new* object with the original's own, enumerable properties plus your `count` property using ES2018 spread notation:

```
x = {...x, count: "20"};
```

...or ES2015's `Object.assign`:

```
x = Object.assign({}, x, {count: "20"});
```

If the array is also sealed or frozen, you can copy it and its objects like this:

```
clientList = clients.map(client => {
    return {...client, count: "20"}; // Or with `Object.assign`
});
```

or even with the concise form of the arrow function:

```
clientList = clients.map(client => ({...client, count: "20"}));
```

---

Side note: This pattern:

```
var clientsList;
Client.find({}, function(err, clients) {
    clientsList = clients; 
    // ...
});
```

...often suggests that you intend to use `clientsList` in code following the `Client.find` call and expect it to have the result from that call's callback. See [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) for why, if you're doing that, it doesn't work.